# How do credit card issuers have enough numbers for virtual CCs?

Tags: credit-card, virtual-credit-card

**Virtual** / **disposable** / **temporary** / **alias** (all common names) credit cards frequently issue new numbers.

How is the cc company able to give out so many numbers? (Especially to a person who uses it very often.)

Do they ever run out? Each time should be different number, do they reuse numbers?

Answer (score 3):

A credit card number contains 16 decimal digits. The first digit specifies the system, and the last is a checksum, leaving us 14 digits that we can freely use.

That's 10^14 combinations, or roughly 13.000 possible cards per human in the world. They won't run out in the foreseeable future.

Also, most virtual cards expire in a couple months, meaning that they could be reused if needed.

Answer (score 2):

I can't speak to the entire industry since it likely varies from card issuer to card issuer.  When I have used a virtual credit card, the generated number has a limited life span.  It also has a credit limit that you can set.  Once it the dollar amount is used up and it expires, the number is available for future usage.

Answer (score 1):

Credit cards numbers are typically 15-19 digits long, and that's actually a lot of numbers. Not all of those numbers are available for card numbers, but  [each issuer still has 1 trillion numbers](https://www.creditcards.com/credit-card-news/credit-card-appearance-1268.php). One of the largest issuers, Visa, as of 2018, has approximately [755 million Visa credit cards in the world](https://www.statista.com/statistics/618115/number-of-visa-credit-cards-worldwide-by-region/). That leaves Visa over 1,000 extra numbers **per existing card** to work with, but only a small percentage of people actually use virtual cards. Furthermore, virtual credit cards are typically short-lived and could be recycled, especially with revolving expiration dates.

To your point though, if every existing Visa card holder started to use virtual numbers on a day to day basis, at some point I suspect Visa would start issuing longer numbers. But I'd guess were many years away from that becoming necessary.

Comment: The "trillion" here is mostly a fiction -- in reality the standard's distinction between "issuer" and "account" number is not followed slavishly. For example, Danish issued VisaDankort cards all have numbers that start with 4571 followed by a 4-digit routing code for the issuing bank branch.That leaves only ten million card numbers per bank branch (still plenty, of course).

Comment: @HenningMakholm - I believe by issuer they meant "Visa", and VisaDankort would be a subset of that, still under the Visa umbrella.

Comment: Still wouldn't make the first six digits an issuer number in practice, because those digits end in the middle of the routing code.